# Proper way to pass a pointer to numpy's structured array from Python to C

Tags: python, c, numpy, ctypes

I want to pass a pointer to numpy's structured array from Python to C. In Python I have:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes as ct

so_file = 'test.so'
my_functions = ct.CDLL(so_file)

nobs = 3
intype = np.dtype([('nobs', np.intc), ('vals', np.double, (nobs, ))])
indata = np.empty(0, dtype=intype)

new_element = (nobs, np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3]))
indata = np.append(indata, np.array(new_element, dtype=intype))

fun = my_functions.my_c_func
fun.restype = None
fun.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(intype)]
fun(indata)
```

while in C I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct intype {
    int nobs;
    double *vals;
} intype;

void my_c_func(intype *indata) {
    intype data;
    data = indata[0];
    printf("%i\n", data.nobs);
    printf("%f\n", data.vals[0]);
}
```

Printing `data.nobs` works, while `data.vals[0]` ends with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I was able to achieve the goal by using `ctype` (without `numpy`) like this:

```
class intype(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('nobs', ct.c_int), ('vals', ct.POINTER(ct.c_double))]

indata = intype()
indata.nobs = ct.c_int(nobs)
indata.vals = (ct.c_double * nobs)(*[1.1, 2.2, 3.3])

fun.argtypes = [ct.POINTER(intype)]
fun(ct.byref(indata))
```

Is it the right way? What are the (dis)advantages of using the first and the second approach?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue comes from a **mismatch between the physical representation used by Numpy and the one declared in your C code**. Indeed, Numpy arrays in a data-type structure are packed contiguously. Such arrays can be seen as plain C arrays (not pointers). Thus, the C declaration must be fixed consequently:

```c
// Better, but incorrect aligned version (see below)
typedef struct intype {
    int nobs;
    double vals[3];
} intype;
```

There is another issue: by default fields of a structure are **aligned to their size** in C. Since `sizeof(int)` is often 4 on most platforms and `sizeof(double)` is 8, the double-precision numbers (`vals`) are aligned in a non-standard way. Compilers typically add some padding to fix this issue. This padding causes another mismatch issue and thus certainly the same result. To solve this, you need to tell the compiler that you want a non-standard packed data structure. There is AFAIK no standard way to do that, but mainstream compilers (GCC, Clang and MSVC) support the the `#pragma pack` directive:

```c
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct intype {
    int nobs;
    double vals[3];
} intype;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

For the types to match between the C code and Numpy, the size of the types must, at least, be the same. That is `indata.itemsize` in Python must be equal to `sizeof(intype)` in C.

Comment: So it's not the right approach then? I've updated the question with the another approach (using ctype pointer) which works as expected. Could you comment on (dis)advantages of not using `numpy` arrays?

Comment: I have written an update but it turns out it hasn't been save :/ . Here is a quick summary: the Numpy solution supports passing multiple items while the second one does not. Numpy is an additional dependencies so if you do not need it and just want to pass informations, then the second approach is better IMHO. If you use Numpy to perform computations, then the former make more sense. The two solutions target different use-cases. For example, the Numpy one cannot be used when the C code is not written/maintained by you because packing is non-standard/not-common.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ctypes` structure that represents the C structure.  You can use `numpy` to create the data array and initialize the structure with its data pointer:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes as ct

class intype(ct.Structure):
    #_pack_ = 1  # eliminates padding generated between int and double* if needed
    _fields_ = (('nobs', ct.c_int),
                ('vals', ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)))  # actual pointer, not array

so_file = 'test.so'
my_functions = ct.CDLL(so_file)

new_element = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3], dtype=ct.c_double)

fun = my_functions.my_c_func
fun.restype = None
fun.argtypes = ct.POINTER(intype)  # correct C intype*

# Use .ctypes.data_as to generate the correct pointer type
indata = intype(len(new_element), new_element.ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)))
fun(ct.byref(indata))
```

Note there is normally padding between a 4-byte `int` and a 64-bit `double*` if your OS is 64-bit.  Use the `_pack_` member if you want to eliminate that, but you also have to pack the C structure.

Comment: I don't see essential difference between your solution and the one in my question's, they both use `ctype` pointers as argtypes. My question is: is it possible to achieve the goal by using `np.ctypeslib.ndpointer` and what are (dis)advantages of using either approach.

Comment: @danas.zuokas You can’t use ndpointer with your approach. If the function took the count and array separately as parameters instead of as a structure you could.

Comment: My solution still uses a numpy array. Your working solution vs. mine would have to be measured to see which is faster to build: a numpy array or a ctypes array.